# posts blocks don't show up correctly

Tags: posts, css

Hi I have the posts available on this page appear well like in this link:
https://teesvg.com/svg-bundles/

but the posts in categories pages don't show up correctly like here:
https://teesvg.com/downloads/category/free-svg-files/

I think it could be fixed by css.
any fix please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the broken page, your per-item div looks like

```html
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" class="edd_download"
     id="edd_download_28068" style="width: 33.3%; float: left;">
```

That `width: 33.3%` is wrong: the containing `<div class="edd_downloads_list edd_download_columns_3">` already does the three column layout, so this extra width style means each item should only use a third of the width of the column. You need to work out where this is coming from in your templates and remove it.

Comment: your solution is great thanks so much I removed the style style="width: 33.3%; float: left and the problem is gone. thanks so much again. but I still have a small problem there are some blanks between posts in many categories like in this category:
https://teesvg.com/downloads/category/teacher-svg/